# What to do next with this indefinite integral?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I'd like to evaluate the following indefinite integral:

$$\displaystyle\int \frac{dx}{(3+x^2)(\sqrt{1+x})}$$

I started by letting $y^2=1+x$ and, after simplifying, got here:

$$ 2\int\frac{dy}{y^4-2y^2+4}$$

I'm not sure what to do next. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factorization you need is
\begin{align}
y^4-2y^2+4&=y^4+4y^2+4-6y^2\\[4px]
&=(y^2+2)^2-(\sqrt{3}\,y)^2\\[4px]
&=(y^2-\sqrt{3}\,y+2)(y^2+\sqrt{3}\,y+2)
\end{align}
Then, with partial fractions,
$$
\frac{1}{(y^2-\sqrt{3}\,y+2)(y^2+\sqrt{3}\,y+2)}=
\frac{Ay+B}{y^2-\sqrt{3}\,y+2}+
\frac{Cy+D}{y^2+\sqrt{3}\,y+2}
$$
and the integral becomes (almost) elementary.

Answer (score 3):

Factor the quartic by noticing it is a quadratic in disguise.  Then seperate using partial fractions.

Comment: sorry ! will u please explain it more , how to factor that

Comment: Let y^2= t. Now you have a quadratic expression in terms of t. After you have factorised, re-substitute.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: for the denominator we get $$3\left(\left(\frac{y^2-1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1\right)$$